# how does skip and take really work?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got 2 queries in LINQ:

```
var users = (
    from u in dataContext.KUserNumbers
    select new {
        u.SubscriberAId,
        u.BNumber,
}).Take(10).ToList();
```

and the result is :

```
341767 HjbZ8UUO3Ob0ubTk5q2GXg
3451645 9PJwin/OEIxY5G1O3Wm0Ow
645560 3Ps6KvC2haleNT0cm+0eeA
5360374 ktJuCU861efptHPtSnYtIQ
5352388 SJKJVqeOMpW3yAFLJeeVaQ
3027301 0N2+LgMCpOKvNLkAjBPicQ
24697284 XhmdWliLn0U4UI+jPeeVDw
23555123 ox2sYcehRXKJW0y1ppTGRg
28920232 G3/EkrSpTOPjGHme8itApw
3032925 j/LQt0BtMohrLG5wqWQW0g
```

and second one:

```
users = (
    from u in dataContext.KUserNumbers
    select new {
        u.SubscriberAId,
        u.BNumber,
}).Skip(1).Take(10).ToList();
```

and I though that result would be sth like:

```
3451645 9PJwin/OEIxY5G1O3Wm0Ow
645560 3Ps6KvC2haleNT0cm+0eeA
5360374 ktJuCU861efptHPtSnYtIQ
5352388 SJKJVqeOMpW3yAFLJeeVaQ
3027301 0N2+LgMCpOKvNLkAjBPicQ
24697284 XhmdWliLn0U4UI+jPeeVDw
23555123 ox2sYcehRXKJW0y1ppTGRg
28920232 G3/EkrSpTOPjGHme8itApw
3032925 j/LQt0BtMohrLG5wqWQW0g
additional one row
```

as I skip one row. but the result is completely different:

```
0 //+SDiKdXKBYAoicCWj7Bw
0 //03hO7doOCyhiopFJ82+w
0 //1iwyah26fjsJrQicb5pA
0 //3KaH4CBH2cI9ACwWf03Q
0 //4mtbXsQIg+QzcqTShPsw
0 //4O6INt73MsCRB6LV480A
0 //8zOGzTdDo7RMIoJLA0Mg
0 //CfYwcShDAgqbq3OCY8Nw
0 //cl71U4qnNfIrXwhsi5WQ
0 //CUIHrC0qHfS10AIihnKw
```

What is the reason for such a behaviour?

thanks for any help

EDIT:

If I Add orderBy subscriberAId after select statement I get:

```
0 Pj5U5pJzrZn4e2Wr4r0H6Q
0 iVu3fam6j3TRbMGdngTtuw
0 i5STtn65LZE7tJfMUPkhug
0 DyhCFKAp5oe0mm5T2Glgpw
0 GaI7ltFJkVeXjMRXShQyLg
0 uneqHdkaBBMeY4Eir7ySZw
0 BAVlunfU4tak4PFY2OxeNg
0 rd4EDeeMUJ/zKDs1IX+Y5w
0 71H3NKg3wLr3/3Iq0HDcEw
0 EeSuYD+003J0g0/ysVteHA

0 nLGfZFEtGnQeJ4I6P8Jy3w
0 B2i5pv26ZzCgi3DISay+Ag
0 57foBJuQV/+6czziRPNQ1A
0 EBBzbvtSDk+T34m+x3F96A
0 BRWpIbeMGQdh/3MANk4AXw
0 0MiqFyqiPpKarJoj/99uMw
0 AdZ6RAHLY86Qe0OG8aZfkw
0 ISSsqPVacX7RQtEwLEWTvw
0 1bPIdr1yDzg8e00gkPmXew
0 k7flvu9G8F8ACWY3zDmSuw
```

updated queries:

```
var users = (
    from u in dataContext.KUserNumbers
    select new {
        u.SubscriberAId,
        u.BNumber,
}).OrderBy(u => u.SubscriberAId).Take(10).ToList();

sers = (
    from u in dataContext.KUserNumbers
    select new {
        u.SubscriberAId,
        u.BNumber,
}).OrderBy(u => u.SubscriberAId).Skip(1).Take(10).ToList();
```

thats more or less how the query generated by linq looks like. What is funny when I use that query in management studio no result are returned. 0 rows :)

```
 SELECT [SubscriberAId], [BNumber]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SubscriberAId]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [SubscriberAId], [BNumber]
    FROM [dbo].[KUserNumber] 
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN 1 + 1 AND 1 + 10
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Comment: What happens if you include an `order by`?

Comment: It is needed before calling Skip and Take

Comment: didnt help :) I edited my answer to see the results

Comment: Please also show the updated queries.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Obviously, sorting by SubscriberAId isn't enough, because it is not unique. Sort by something unique, e.g. BNumber - if it really is unique.

Answer (score 3):

As for how these linq methods "really work" the best resource I have found for such understanding is Jon Skeet's Reimplementing Linq to Objects, for Skip/Take:

https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx

As for why the two linq queries you are running are having that effect, I can only anticipate that dataContext.KUserNumbers does not enumerate in a specific order? Try introducing an OrderBy after the select statements in both queries to see if it gives a more obvious result.

In case you enjoy the article you can find the whole series here:

http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html

Another good resource for debugging when you are specifically using linq2sql is the Debug Visualizer which will allow you to see the queries which will be passed on to the database layer. This often give an incite into anything unusual being requested from the db:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx

Comment: List to objects is not the focus here. In linq2sql, the C# code will be translated to SQL. So the real question is: How does the data provider of linq2sql for the database the OP uses translate Skip and Take to SQL?

Comment: I agree that it's not the focus, however looking at how they are implemented in linq2objects can sometimes give a real incite into what there true functionality is / intended.

Comment: I have added a link to details about how to use the Debug Visualizer  which can help when looking into problems with link2sql.

Comment: @roja: What I am trying to say is: The implementation of Skip and Take in Linq to objects has NOTHING to do with the implementation of Skip and Take in linq2sql, because in linq2sql, those methods aren't even executed in C# code. It goes something like this: *If user added a call to Skip in his code, create the following SQL: xyz*

Comment: Daniel, I get what your saying I simply don't agree that no incite can be gleaned from the alternate implementations... Sure enough in linq2sql it's likely to be emitting something like: SELECT TOP x SKIP y FROM z but if your trying to investigate odd behaviour it can be nice, as a programmer, to see an implementation of the specification.

Comment: @roja: It's simply something else completely, so the implementation in C# really doesn't help him.

Comment: The first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of 'why', I recommend inspecting the generated SQL [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx).  This will tell you how the Skip is being interpreted.

That said, if the Skip count is always a relatively small number, a simple practical solution is to `Take(N+k).ToList().Skip(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

haha :)

adding

.ThenBy(u=>u.BNumber)   solved the problem. It means that You can never be sure what is the result especially if the table is big (problably if is on more than one page in sql server).

You need to provide good sorting (try to make rows distinct)